# How do I get more space between labels on the y axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
dt5 <- gapminder %>%
  filter(continent == "Asia" & year == 2007)
dt5
ggplot(dt5, 
       aes(x=lifeExp, 
           y=reorder(country, lifeExp))) +
  geom_point(size = 3,color="blue") +
  geom_segment(aes(x = 40,   # 起始位置
               xend = lifeExp, 
               y = reorder(country, lifeExp), 
               yend = reorder(country, lifeExp)),
               color = "lightgrey") +
  labs (x = "Life Expectancy (years)",
        y = "",
        title = "Life Expectancy by Country",
        subtitle = "GapMinder data for Asia - 2007") +
  theme_minimal() + 
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank())
```

I want more space between the lines, I think the current picture is too crowded

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CBx7k.png)

Answer (score 0):

Since you only want more space between all labels, I think you can simply solve this by saving your plot with  `ggsave()` and specifying a width and height argument.

Two examples:

```
ggsave('version1.png', width = 6, height = 6)
```

[image: lollipop chart with little space between y labels]

```
ggsave('version2.png', width = 6, height = 10)
```

[image: lollipo chart with large space between y labels]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It's very convenient :)